# Copy dll modified in post-build to obj folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, build, msbuild

Is there a way to get a dll updated in a post-build-event copied into the ***/obj*** folder?

Modifying the dll (to embed some generated files) in the post-build works fine, but after a ReBuild, the ***/obj*** folder always contains the 'old' dll (before the post-build event is triggered).

This causes problems when building other projects (which seem to use the 'wrong' dll from ***/obj*** folder in some cases).

Can this be done automatically, or is it only possibly via another post-build-command to copy the dll by hand?

Comment: Have you tried adding a copy to the postbuild event? And eventually a delete in a prebuild event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this be done automatically, or is it only possibly via another post-build-command to copy the dll by hand?

The answer is yes, you can add a xcopy command after Modifying the dll in post-build-command:

```
echo Execute Modifying dll Event.
xcopy.exe "$(ProjectDir)TheModifyiedFolder\Modifying.dll" "$(ProjectDir)obj" /y /s
```

Comment: Thanks!, I finally got it to work that way. In addition I added two cases to check for Debug or Release configuration and copy from/to the appropriate folders.